# SML Parsing with Multiple Parsers

Tags: parsing, sml

I'm trying to implement a function that will take a list of parsers and tries them one by one until one suceeds. If no parser in the list succeeds then the overall parser fails. Here is my attempt:

```
    fun oneOf [] = NONE
      | oneOf (p::ps) = fn inp => case parse p inp of
              NONE => oneOf ps
            | SOME (v,out) => SOME (v,out)
```

I am getting many operator/operand do not agree errors. Any hints on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in the first case, which should yield a function, too. Furthermore, you need to pass on `inp` in the recursive call. That is:

```
fun oneOf [] = fn inp => NONE
  | oneOf (p::ps) = fn inp => case parse p inp of
          NONE => oneOf ps inp
        | SOME (v,out) => SOME (v,out)
```

Or shorter:

```
fun oneOf [] inp = NONE
  | oneOf (p::ps) inp =
    case parse p inp of
        NONE => oneOf ps inp
      | some => some
```

Answer (score 0):

Your types don't match. With `oneOf []`, you return `NONE`, which is an `option` type. With `oneOf (p::ps)` you instead return an anonymous function that returns an `option`.  Presumably, you'll want to apply that anonymous function to something.